# CodeIgniter 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, internal-server-error

I downloaded a PHP script written using CodeIgniter. when I run it from the localhost, on going to the admin folder, it shows localhost again. Also when running from my web host, it shows a 500 Internal Server Error.

I run the site from http://localhost/myproj It works. Then when I try to go to the admin page which is at http://localhost/myproj/administrator, it gives a 500 Internal Server Error.

I read here that this might be due to a wrong code in the .htaccess file. This is my present .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

```
# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Please help me. I know it might be a very small problem, but I'm unable to find the error.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem with 500 errors (with CodeIgniter), with different apache settings, it displays 500 error when there's an error with PHP configuration.

Here's how it can trigger 500 error with CodeIgniter:

1. Error in script (PHP misconfigurations, missing packages, etc...)
2. PHP "Fatal Errors"

Please check your apache error logs, there should be some interesting information in there.

Comment: thank you, this helped me figure out the server's rewrite_module was not loaded.

Comment: This also helped me, turns out a hook i had installed was using a function from a helper that wasn't loaded!  That's hours of my life spent debugging that i want back.

Comment: Please check your apache error logs +1 i just could not find out what my error is until i see this

Comment: Error logs did the trick. In Ubuntu 16.04, apache logs can be found /var/log/apache2

Comment: thank you, in centos7 the problem I found the cause on /var/log/httpd

Comment: My problem was in the log, the .env file was not readable and all I had to do was use chmod command in centos 7

Answer (score 5):

Just in case somebody else stumbles across this problem, I inherited an older CodeIgniter project and had a lot of trouble getting it to install.

I wasted a ton of time trying to create a local installation of the site and tried everything. In the end, the solution was simple.

The problem is that older CodeIgniter versions (like 1.7 and below), don't work with PHP 5.3. The solution is to switch to PHP 5.2 or something older.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to remove index.php from your site URL's, correct?

Try setting your `$config['uri_protocol']` to `REQUEST_URI` instead of `AUTO`.

Comment: Thankyou so much. After hours of searching, this was the problem to my solution

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your root `index.php` file has the correct permission, its permission must be `0755` or `0644`

Comment: this is not worked for me.

Comment: @IlhamSafeek try to use other solutions mentioned on this page. Check your PHP version as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this to your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule >
```

Answer (score 2):

remove comment in httpd.conf (apache configuration file):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I run CodeIgniter in a sub directory I set the `RewriteBase` to it. Try setting it as `/myproj/` instead of `/`.

Comment: Tried it. But still same error. When I check the Log file on my web host, I see the following error.
Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index:  LOGIN_USERNAME

Comment: What is your `$config['base_url']` and `$config['uri_protocol']` set to in the `/config/config.php`?  Also, is the `LOGIN_USERNAME` something in your CI code or maybe in your web root?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/myproj/";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
I removed the LOGIN_USERNAME variable from the code.

Comment: Try blanking out the `base_url`. Also, in your `/index.php` file make sure `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` is set to `development` and that in your `php.ini` your `display_errors` is set to `On`.

Comment: Tried everything but still no luck. I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Check into your error logs again to see if there are any errors.  Something should be logged with that type of error.

Comment: This was the log details in the wamp folder (access.log file)

127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2011:18:47:46 +0530] "GET /myproj/administrator HTTP/1.1" 200 4629
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2011:18:47:46 +0530] "GET /myproj/index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 400 543
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2011:18:47:46 +0530] "GET /myproj/index.php?img=pngFolderGo HTTP/1.1" 400 543
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2011:18:47:46 +0530] "GET /myproj/index.php?img=pngPlugin HTTP/1.1" 400 543

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late, but this will help someone.

Check if rewrite engine is [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9021425/3843374).

If not, enable rewrite engine and restart server.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

if The wampserver Version 2.5 then change apache configuration as

**httpd.conf (apache configuration file):**
From

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**
```

To ,delete the #

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**
```

this working fine to me

Answer (score 1):

Pretty late to the party but, i think the best approach to 500 internal server errors in CodeIgniter would be to enable the error log functionality in the Config.php file in the config folder and set a threshold value i.e. $config['log_threshold'] = 1,2,3,4 depending on the logs you want to view.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't relevant any more to this thread, but hopefully helpful to somebody.
I've had 500 errors for the past hour as I had a controller return an array not supported by the php version ran on my (crappy) server. Seems trivial but had the hallmarks of a codeigniter error.

I had to use:

```
class emck_model extends CI_Model {

    public function getTiles(){

        return array(...);

    }

}
```

Instead of

```
class emck_model extends CI_Model {

    public function getTiles(){

        return [...];

    }

}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule >
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using local server, this problem is faced in Wampserver when the essential modules are not enable.

You can Enable them with:

Left click on Wampsever icon

Go to APACHE -> APACHE MODULES

scroll down and find "rewrite_module" and "headers_module"

Then mark them check

It will restart automatically. Done.

[image]