# How to check if mod_rewrite is enabled in php?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, iis

I was wondering if it is possible to check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled on **Apache** AND **IIS** in **`PHP`**.

**ModRewrite** for IIS exists. Check it [`here`](http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/ModRewrite.html).

So, I'm looking for a PHP script that checks for `mod_rewrite` on **Apache** and **IIS.**

Does anyone know such script or can write one?

Especially for Microsoft **IIS**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If you're using mod_php, you can use `apache_get_modules()`. This will return an array of all enabled modules, so to check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled, you could simply do

```
in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules());
```

Unfortunately, you're most likely trying to do this with CGI, which makes it a little bit more difficult.

You can test it using the following, though

```
strpos(shell_exec('/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -l'), 'mod_rewrite') !== false
```

If the above condition evaluates to `true`, then `mod_write` is enabled.

Comment: I don't know. This tests for if the module `mod_rewrite` is installed. The _IIS Mod-Rewrite_ module you're probably referring to is an entirely different and commercial product - it has no association with the Apache module, it's an entirely different question and I have no experience using it.

Comment: That's true, so there is properly no general script?

Comment: @DrCord Then I'm guessing you're using it in CGI.

Comment: nope, was using it in a php script just like the answer and the answer below. if( ! function_exists('apache_get_modules') ){ phpinfo(); die; } always is true on my server...

Comment: Your PHP script could very easily be CGI.

Comment: @kba I dont know what path to pass in my shared server to shell_exec, I tried getting it through SHELL command but i dont have permissions for this and $_SERVER['path'] is not  working at all.

Comment: Does this return true if the module is installed, or enabled? For me it's returning true as the module is installed, but disabled.

Comment: thanks, here is the full code: <?php
if (in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())) {echo "mod_rewrite is active";}
else {echo "mod_rewrite is NOT active";};
?>

Comment: Why not go with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`? It shows really important data, including Apache modules loaded

Comment: @Gerep `phpinfo()` can be useful for many things, but if you want to write a system that uses `mod_rewrite` if it's enabled or otherwise fallbacks to some other behaviour, it be useful to detect it programmatically.

Comment: tried `strpos(shell_exec('/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -l'), 'mod_rewrite') !== false`
 it give `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `shell_exec'`

Answer (score 96):

#### Copy this piece of code and run it to find out.

---

```
<?php
 if(!function_exists('apache_get_modules') ){ phpinfo(); exit; }
 $res = 'Module Unavailable';
 if(in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules())) 
 $res = 'Module Available';
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>A mod_rewrite availability check !</title></head>
<body>
<p><?php echo apache_get_version(),"</p><p>mod_rewrite $res"; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will phpinfo also tell me if I don't have mod_php enabled?

Comment: yes we can see in phpinfo.php  all Apche's  "Loaded Modules"

Answer (score 54):

I like [Christian Roy's solution](http://christian.roy.name/blog/detecting-modrewrite-using-php):

```
###  .htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Tell PHP that the mod_rewrite module is ENABLED.
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # The rest of your rewrite rules here

</IfModule>
```

Then, you can check in your PHP code for

```
    array_key_exists('HTTP_MOD_REWRITE', $_SERVER);
```

No idea if this works also with IIS (I have no way to check) but the odds are good.

Comment: With a `<IfModule mod_env.c>` it would be almost perfect. :)

Comment: This is a very useful and simple solution and it works even if PHP is running as CGI

Comment: as @RibeiroBreno mentioned, with <IfModule mod_env.c> it would be almost perfect. this worked for me perfectly.

Comment: If PHP is running as CGI, this is the way to go. Works beautifully.

Comment: Thank you!  @a.l.e

Comment: I like this idea. Another advantage : this will indirectly also check if the .htaccess was taken into account.

Comment: @RibeiroBreno doing this with `<IfModule mod_env.c>` is exactly what MyBB does: https://github.com/mybb/mybb/blob/mybb_1837/htaccess.txt#L49-L51 and https://github.com/mybb/mybb/blob/mybb_1837/inc/init.php#L239

Answer (score 35):

Upload a file called info.php with this code and run it:

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
```

Search for mod_rewrite on the page, and see if you can find it under Loaded Modules.

Answer (score 28):

don't make it so difficult you can simply find in `phpinfo();`

[image]

Hope helpful!

Thanks

Comment: This was the quickest and simplest route for me, since I was already doing stuff with a phpinfo call/file. Thanks! :)

Comment: @loyola , I can't update my comment, so I deleted, thank

Answer (score 11):

via command line we in centOs we can do this

```
httpd -l
```

Comment: And if you are on ubuntu: apache2 -l

Comment: Or **apachectl -M** in Ubuntu as well

Comment: This seems to show only modules that were compiled in.

Comment: __httpd -M__ shows list of loaded Static and Shared modules.

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Look under Configuration in the apache2handler in the Loaded Modules row.

This is simple and works.

```
<?php foreach( apache_get_modules() as $module ) echo "$module<br />";  ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is my current method of checking if Mod_rewrite enabled for both Apache and IIS

```
/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------
 *  MOD REWRITE CHECK
 * --------------------------------------------------------------
 *                                        - By A H Abid
 * Define Constant for MOD REWRITE
 * 
 * Check if server allows MOD REWRITE. Checks for both 
 * Apache and IIS.
 * 
 */
if( function_exists('apache_get_modules') && in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules()) )
    $mod_rewrite = TRUE;
elseif( isset($_SERVER['IIS_UrlRewriteModule']) )
    $mod_rewrite = TRUE;
else
    $mod_rewrite = FALSE;
define('MOD_REWRITE', $mod_rewrite);
```

It works in my local machine and also worked in my IIS based webhost. However, on a particular apache server, it didn't worked for Apache as the apache_get_modules() was disabled but the mod_rewrite was enable in that server.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of installed [apache modules](https://www.php.net/apache_get_modules), and check against that. Perhaps you can check if its installed by searching for its .dll (or linux equivalent) file.

Comment: @kba How to check for then in CGI mode.

Answer (score 3):

Two lines of code:

```
$isEnabled = in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules());
echo ($isEnabled) ? 'Enabled' : 'Not enabled';
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea, indeed more a dirty hack, regarding mod rewrite is server dependend an not necessary a php issue:
Why not, if you have the possibillity, create a test directory put a .htaccess in it rewriting to test.php, call the directory via http and check if you get the expected result you put in test.php.

Indeed, dirty.

Comment: I created a library that builds on this exact idea: https://github.com/rosell-dk/htaccess-capability-tester

Answer (score 1):

One more method through [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

```
exec('/usr/bin/httpd -M | find "rewrite_module"',$output);
```

If `mod_rewrite` is loaded it will return "rewrite_module" in output.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
function apache_module_exists($module)
{
    return in_array($module, apache_get_modules());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For IIS heros and heroins:**

No need to look for mod_rewrite. 
Just install **[Rewrite 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337)** module and then import **.htaccess** files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just because a module is loaded, it does not necessarily mean that the directives has been enabled in the directory you are placing the .htaccess. What you probably need is to know: Does rewriting work? The only way to find out for sure is to do an actual test: Put some test files on the server and request it with HTTP.

Good news: I created [a library](https://github.com/rosell-dk/htaccess-capability-tester) for doing exactly this (detecting various .htaccess capabilities). With this library, all you need to do is this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use HtaccessCapabilityTester\HtaccessCapabilityTester;

$hct = new HtaccessCapabilityTester($baseDir, $baseUrl);
if ($hct->rewriteWorks()) {    
    // rewriting works
}
```

(instead of $baseDir and $baseUrl, you must provide the path to where the test files are going to be put and a corresponding URL to where they can be reached)

If you just want to know if the module is loaded, you can do the following:

```
if ($hct->moduleLoaded('rewrite')) {    
    // mod_rewrite is loaded (tested in a real .htaccess by using the "IfModule" directive)
}
```

The library is available here: https://github.com/rosell-dk/htaccess-capability-tester