# nice urls in modx rev - getting 403

Tags: .htaccess, modx

I get 403 error after i turn on nice url in settings.
Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Settings are set the same way, i have on different website, where nice urls works fine.
I have clear cache.

When i add to a page `<a href="[[~1]]" title="some title">Some Page</a>`, i get correct link, but after i go to this page, again i get 403 page. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I believe that 403 messages is to do with FollowSymlinks. Try enabling it by adding `Options +FollowSymlinks`

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess appears to be correct [it's the default]

- delete all your cache files from the disk, don't just clear the cache from the manager.
- check that: 'Check for Duplicate URIs Across All Contexts', 'Use Friendly Alias Path' are checked, that the resources actually have an alias.

However, you are getting a 403 & not a 404? Pretty sure you should be getting a 404 error have you set up resource groups? Make sure you are a member of that group when you are testing.

Comment: thank, i will check and clear all cache from server. Also i didnt hide any content, restrict pages or so. So for all users it should be visible. And yes, i get 403 error, and this text: `You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.`.

Comment: hmm strange, and this only starts after you enable furls? check that mod_rewrite is available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php [though you should be getting a 500 error if it wasn't] have you posted in the modx user forums?