# Cannot remove index.php from url CI based site

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I have Code Igniter based site and I have it on ubuntu 12.04 in /var/www/mysite folder 
My ubuntu serves as a server so I access my site trough other computer, but both computers are on LAN network. I use http://xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt/mysite url to access it.

The problem I have is that I cannot use url without "index.php" in it.
So I have http://xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt/mysite/index.php/phpinfo To acces my controller phpinfo instead of http://xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt/mysite/phpinfo

I have cheked well that mod_revrite works well with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php)
And also checked that the folder, files and subfolders in mysite have all 777 file permissions.

I also added all necessary rules in .htaccess file but still no success

Any idea what is causing this.

Comment: What do you have in .htaccess (for DirectoryIndex)? Have you restarted the web server?

Comment: Well there is no section DirectoryIndex.

Comment: Have you read the documentation regarding removing index.php. Once you've added your .htaccess file, you will need to tell CI to stop adding index.php to the links.

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: Yeah I copied all the lines for removing index.php from url but still the same.

Comment: I btw have some <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> and <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c> sections. Where should I put the lines???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what was the issue.

The default file in sites-available had option

AllowOverride None for /var/wwww

I set it to All and it worked out. :)

cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is make sure you followed all of the [CI instructions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

It may be that you did not update the config file to be a blank string rather than using index.php

Comment: You mean this $config['index_page'] = ''; It is empty

Comment: Like Keaton said above, have you restarted your apache?