# How to remove index.php from codeigniter in UBUNTU

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I know this question is being ask already, i tried all those but still unable to remove index.php from url.
Here are my details

```
Ubuntu 12.10
PHP : 5.4.6
Mod_rewrite in on
CI verson: 2.1
```

.htacess look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectname

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I also look at the below link but no luck..
[Cannot remove index.php from url CI based site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580970/cannot-remove-index-php-from-url-ci-based-site)

[How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

My "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default"  is look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None 
        </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Anything suspicious in your logs?

Comment: And what is your `$config['uri_protocol']` set to?

Comment: And, lastly, what error do you get. I suspect "Object Not Found"?

Comment: @MikeAnthony  i am getting "The requested URL /projectname/aboutus was not found on this server."

Comment: And the other questions? Also, what happens when you visit the `projectname` root? And, what happens when you visit the root of the host (`localhost`)?

Comment: @MikeAnthony when i am accessing "localhost/projectname/" it is loading correctly but when i navigate to any other controller than i need to type index.php otherwise it give me above error.

Comment: @MikeAnthony: how can i know where is log file.

Comment: It should be here: `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Try turning `MultiViews` off by changing it to `-MultiViews` under `<Directory /var/www/>`

Comment: @MikeAnthony: change to "-MultiViews" but no success.

Comment: @MikeAnthony: error log logs as "[Wed May 15 11:21:43 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/projectname/aboutus"

Comment: See this answer from the possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7930935/1626250

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `application/config/config.php` change:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

it is a good idea to do apache reload everytime you change an apache config file.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

or:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

or:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd reload
```

(or whatever is the equivalent command for your platform)

for what it is worth, here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|uploads|googlexxxxxxxx\.html|mobile.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: yes i updated that one also.

Comment: yes restarted my apache number of time. no use.

Comment: tried with your htaccess file no success. i change "RewriteBase /projectname" as my ci is under this folder.

Comment: It work like a charm.
Thx so much!

Comment: RELOAD THE APACHE!!!

Answer (score 70):

**Step 1 :**

Add this in htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Step 2 :**

Remove index.php in codeigniter config

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**Step 3 :**

Allow overriding htaccess in Apache Configuration (Command)

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and edit the file & change to

```
AllowOverride All
```

for www folder

**Step 4 :**

Enabled apache mod rewrite (Command)

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

**Step 5 :**

Restart Apache (Command)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Finally! a working solution. Setp `5` can also be simply: `service apache2 restart`

Comment: Yes this solution is working for codeigniter 3.x + ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I highly recommend this solution for Codeigniter 3, LAMP and Ubuntu 14

Comment: I was missing the AllowOveride All - works now. thanks!

Comment: Verified works in Ubuntu 16.04, LAMP + Code Igniter 3. Thanks! :)

Comment: I tried above solution but didn't work, tried above command to allow overiding in apache configuration but I am getting `Directory '/etc/apache2' does not exist` this response in terminal. I am using ubuntu version 17.04 and CI version 3.

Comment: Many thanks! Worked on codeigniter 3 + ubuntu 16.04 lamp presintalled digitalocean

Comment: Step 3 (AllowOverride All) turned out to be the crucial step! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried this no success

Comment: change httpd.conf,       AllowOverride None  -> AllowOverride All

Comment: It looks like it already is: See `<Directory /var/www/>` in the asker's code.

Comment: @blu: i change "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" and restarted my apache but no success.

Comment: create a new directory, test your web server supports rewrite.