# CodeIgniter URL Rewrite Issue

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am making application in codeigniter and now uploading to GoDaddy server but getting 404 error.

My code is like this

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING";
```

.htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

I am getting value like

```
http://yourdomain.com/index.php?controller/action/etc
```

But i need

```
http://yourdomain.com/controller/action/etc
```

Please help.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: @Hussaintamboli in godaddy urls are like.../index.php?..

Comment: I don't know about godaddy urls but To pass everything after `http://yourdomain.com` in CI do the above thing. If you want to add some exceptions for say `images` i.e. you don't want `http://yourdomain.com/images/image.png` to follow above rule, put this just above it - ` RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: But is there any need of `+FollowSymLinks` in this answer? for @chirag

Comment: @hussain tamboli : no

Comment: @chirag Okay. Don't forget to use `AllowOverride All` in `Directory` directive of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/<your core config file>. This way `.htaccess` is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Comment: try that for your htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try this... it should work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sgu_portal
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|css|js|images|img|less|player-skin|robots\.txt|opensearch\.xml|favicon\.ico|assets|forums)
```

input your folder CSS,js,images or else. If not your css not working.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

and in CI Config

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this answer

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/16558169/1182195*

make sure that your server configuration is set to

1 . *Enabled mod rewrite*

2 . *Allow overriding htaccess in your apache*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answer Thank you so much but correct answer is like this
code of htaccess file is like this

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```