# Codeigniter have tried many ways removing index.ph from url then not works

Tags: php, codeigniter

here if i user

```
http://myproject/index.php/control/one
```

here it will work if i change to

```
http://myproject/control/one
```

here it give error of

```
Not Found

The requested URL /myproject/da/topic_c was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at 10.0.2.139 Port 80
```

**i am using on local**

no i have set my .httaccess file to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

the rest project fine...

Comment: where is your domain name in your URL ? You mapped `myproject` to an IP address in HOSTS file?

Comment: on local network, like i am 10.0.0.1 it is on 10.0.2.139 so here http://10.0.2.139/mproject/index/any ... it works but not if i remove index.php

Comment: in common practice, we use local domain name such as `myproject.local` for easier identification, and conform to URI format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556915/how-to-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-in-ubuntu/16558169#16558169

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: yes, RewriteEngine on

Answer (score 0):

U can try this, This is my Codeigniter .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed value of index_page variable in config.php?
Go to application/config/config.php find $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; and replace with $config['index_page'] = '';