# Cannot remove index.php from Codeigniter for Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter-3, ubuntu-17.10

The last one I follow is here [How to remove index.php from codeigniter in UBUNTU [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556915/how-to-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-in-ubuntu)

I have one controller that look like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login.html');
    }
}
```

When I access it by this URL: `http://localhost/homerent/Login`, I got 404 not found.

I follow from answer above in referent link by

1. $config['index_page'] = '';
2. restart apache2 service: sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
3. Add below code to `/var/www/html/my_ci_site/.htaccess`

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|uploads|googlexxxxxxxx\.html|mobile.html)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
   ```
4. Replace every instance of `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
5. Enable rewrite mode: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
6. Finally restart apache2 service again.

After all, I access my url again `http://localhost/homerent/Login` I still get 404 not found.

I have no clue what is wrong with that.

Comment: make sure mod rewrite is enabled if not enable it and restart apache.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy, sure I did with this command `sudo a2enmod rewrite` but it was still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu You have to do virtual host to working.
For this first in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` create `yourproject.conf` file(may be you may need root permissions use `sudo` command)

For this in terminal

```
 cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Then

`sudo nano yourproject.conf`

Copy below content and paste into it

```
<VirtualHost *:3434>
      ServerName  localhost

      DirectoryIndex index.php
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yourprojectfolder

      <Directory "/var/www/html/yourprojectfolder">
      Options All
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from all
      </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Note:You can use different ports here

Then run

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf`

In this file add line (Do not edit existing ports )

`Listen 3434`

Then run

`sudo a2ensite yourproject.conf
 sudo a2enmod rewrite`

in `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:3434';
$config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Create .htaccess inside `yourproject` folder with below content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then restart apache to take effect the changes

Now you can access your site through the url `http://localhost:3434`(This will load the defaulf controller) and no need to add the project folder in the url

for example `http://localhost/homerent/Login` is the url using now and
After setting up virtual host 
You can use `http://localhost:3434/Login`