# ModX Revo: friendly URLs not working

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url, modx, modx-revolution

This seems to be a common issue but I have tried all the suggestions and none work.

The issue is when I turn on Friendly URLs in ModX Revo all my links get broken (404s). The URLS do appear correct with the alias after them.

Heres what I've tried:

- Changing ht.access to .htaccess
- Ensuring the correct path is present in `MODX_BASE_PATH` in the
  confic.inc.php file
- Ensuring all FURL settings in System Settings are ok and correct
- Clearing browser and ModX caches

If anyone can suggest something I've missed that would be great! Thanks

Comment: have you verified that mod_rewrite is installed and working?

Comment: @SeanKimball No I havent - can you elaborate?

Comment: take a peek here, though if mod_rewrite was not enabled I would think you would be getting a 500 error when trying to use it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php

Comment: At the top of your .htaccess you should have `RewriteBase /`. If MODX is in a subfolder, change to `RewriteBase /foldername`

Comment: @okyanet - yep this is present. Still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I set FURL Lowercase Alias's to 'No' in the ModX System Settings and it now works... I do not know why but there you have it...

Perhaps this is because I specified the Resources Alias' before I turned FURLs on and thus they did not actually convert them to lower case

Answer (score 1):

Need some mroe info:

Are you developing locally (WAMP, MAMP..)? If you are make sure that you have mod_rewire enabled in  your apache settings. If not make sure it's enabled with your host.

Are you typing the urls in the browser manually (without wayfinder)? (www.yoursite.com/somepage)

Comment: im developing on a live server (Centos LAMP). I have tried acessing the page with wayfinder links, page preview and typing in the URL.

Comment: I've also added mod_rewrite as well - no luck

Comment: I'm thinking it has to be something with the configuration in the htaccess file.. do you have strict SEO URLs enabled? if you so there is section in that file that needs to be uncommented. I've had many issues like this in the past, but the solution has always been something different.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question but I just install REVO tonight and had issues with FURLs returning 404 errors after I enabled all the settings. What I DIDN'T do was rename the htaccess. Once I renamed that to .htaccess everything is fine. Stupid mistake made with too little sleep but I thought I should post it in hopes I can save someone some wasted time.