# Wrong 301 htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

I have this code on my site and I need to redirect the http://softsolutions.fr to http://www.softsolutions.fr, but it is not redirecting:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  Options +Indexes
  RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^softsolutions\.fr
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.softsolutions.fr/index.html [R=301,L]     

  RewriteRule    ^$    /index.html    [L]

    # Rewrites "sub.domain.foo/anything" to "sub.domain.foo/anything.php"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+).php$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+).pdf$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+).(html|htm)$
    RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_/]*)$    /$1.php    [L]  

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is mod_rewrite available and `AllowOverride` in httpd.conf set to allow .htaccess rewrites for that site?

Comment: I'm a newbie to this issue, I don't know how to make sure of what you asked me, can u help, so I can understand well?

Comment: What I'm asking is basically, is any redirection at all working?

Answer (score 0):

Replace those lines:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^softsolutions\.fr
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.softsolutions.fr/index.html [R=301,L]
```

With:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^softsolutions\.fr [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: :( Nope, didn't work, is there anything related to permissions?

Comment: you should ask your host provider.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php or remove the surrounding `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> </IfModule>` if you got error like `500, Internal Server Error` then it's not available, therefor you have to ask your host provider to enable it.

Comment: Hello Gustonez, I removed the <IfModule> tag and it did not give the error, then it is enabled right?