# How to Call codeigniter controller function without url without index

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I want to call codeigniter controller class function Like this. but this is not working 
i want remove index.php from URL

[image]

With index.php this working well How to Remove index.php from url ?

[image]

I changed

```
   $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

To

```
   $config['index_page'] = '';
```

but it's not worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do two job to remove the index.php from the URL.

**1st Job -**

changed the config file

```
 $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

To

```
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

(Which you have already done)

**2nd Job -**

You have to add a .htaccess file in your root directory and make sure that your php  mod_rewrite is enabled.

For more info, please refer the [RewriteRule](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks/) docs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Just try this. Hope it works and let me know whats going on.

Comment: How to check your mod_rewrite is enable or not?-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php

How to enable mod_rewrite- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Answer (score 3):

Create .htaccess file in your root directory with the following content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

A nice list of examples using .htaccess can be found here http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted, it will help others to see the valid answer straight away

Comment: goto: codeigniter user guide (Docs » General Topics » CodeIgniter URLs)

Answer (score 1):

Add this .htaccess file in your root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Try this code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create the htaccess file in the below location if you are using xampp

" htdocs/codeigniter/.htaccess "

and then put htaccess content

Answer (score 0):

The change to `$config['index_page']` was right, but you need 1 more thing to do:

You have to use an `.htaccess` file in your codeigniter root directory that redericts all calls to the `index.php` file without the need to have `index.php` in the url bar

My file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce www
    # If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
    # the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.YOURSITE.COM/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce NO www
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://YOURSITE.COM/$1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

This file also redericts all non www calls ( like  `YOURSITE.com` to `www.YOURSITE.com`. You can also do it the other way, then you have to comment the parts ( with an `#` ) and uncommend the part below it.

Also it makes the urls better (canocalized URL). if you take a look at the following URLS:

```
/category
/category/index
/category/index/
```

That are 3 url's for the same function in the same controller. With the `.htaccess` provided above, the url will be

```
/category
```

Another important thing to note: for controllers with an `index` method which take any sort of parameter, these URLs will still work as such:

```
/welcome/index/123
/category/index/123
```