# CodeIgniter doesn't display website properly on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

I created a site in PHP using CodeIgniter framework. When it was done, I edited `routes.php` file and added .htaccess file to eliminate `/index.php/` part from URL.

Now, when I try to open it in localhost, it works fine, I can access `http://localhost/mysite` and get the landing page I wanted.

But, the problem is when I try to access the site on server, I get an error. So if I open something like `http://mysite.com` I get CodeIngniters' default 404 page. I can open all other pages if I specify their URL, like: `http://mysite.com/about` but when someone else opens the site, he gets an error and he doesn't know what to type in order to pass by that error.

What should I do to fix this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you show us what changes you made to each file mentioned?

Comment: I'm thinking the error is with the htaccess file specifically

Comment: did you change the contents of config.php ?

Comment: @Dale I edited the question with htaccess code
@ VinodVT Yes, of course.

Comment: try removing the ? from `index.php?/$1`

Comment: what editings are made on routes.php ?

Comment: Have you tried using the official htaccess rewrite from [codeigniter user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)? it always works for me (except on godaddy hosting)

Comment: Have a look in this post ..... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852585/how-to-call-codeigniter-controller-function-without-url-without-index/17852790#17852790

Comment: Removing ? didn't work. Neither did official htaccess rewrite from codeigniter user guide.

Comment: @SharifUlIslam Nope, doesn't work :(

Comment: @VinodVT I edited some routes and set default controller (it has index() function, so if nothing else is matched, it should open default_controller/index), and it all works in localhost, but not on server.

Answer (score 0):

This .htaccess code works for me always, you can try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess does raise some concerns, you are attempting to pass the file location as a query string which may work in CodeIgniter but there is a better way of doing this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Also, make sure in your config.php you have the following option set:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This .htaccess code works

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And in config

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: No. It still gives me 404.

Comment: Give us your routes.php

Comment: And $config['base_url'] = 'YOUR WEBSITE';

Comment: base_url is set.
Here's routes.php:

<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    $route['default_controller'] = "MasterKontroler";
    $route['404_override'] = '';

    $route['admin/(:any)']="AdminKontroler/$1";
    $route['firma/(:any)'] = "FirmaKontroler/$1";
    $route['kontakt'] = "MasterKontroler/kontaktirajteNas";
    $route['login'] = "MasterKontroler/index";
    $route['pretrazi'] = "MasterKontroler/pretrazi";

MasterKontroler has index() function and everything works in localhost. But landing page on server shows CI 404 page.

Comment: At end of routes try add   $route["(.*)"] = 'MasterKontroler';

Comment: In default_controller, do you have                              public function index()
 {
  $this->MasterKontroler();
 }

Comment: MasterKontroler is default controller. In it, I have public function index that loads some view.

Comment: i dont know why you dont call controller in CI index() ? It is model for CI?

Comment: class MasterKontroler extends CI_Controller {
  

 public function index()
 {
  $this->home();
 }
 
 public function home()
 { etc..... }

Comment: I tried that, but, as I expected, it didn't work. Basically, this doesn't "bring" anything new, it just adds one reference to index call.

The code is good. It works. The only thing that bothers me is that it doesn't show the landing page on server. I also had some issues with models (could not find models), which I resolved by changing names of PHP files in "models" folder to lower case: MyModel.php -> mymodel.php (?!)

I assume the problem here is something trivial, similar to this thing with models.

Comment: Look in controllers folder maybe issuse is with MasterKontroler on server Masterkontroler

Comment: Or simple idea, rename anywhere MasterKontroler to masterkontroler

Comment: Tried that. It just doesn't show the view needed when I look for mysite.com but it works with i.e mysite.com/login. Every controller, view or model works, but it wont show landing page mysite.com

Comment: Tried all just last thing $config['uri_protocol']='AUTO';