# htaccess - Redirect all except subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my old site (http://festival.launch.co) to the new site (http://events.launch.co/festival). However, there is one subdirectory (2013) that I don't want to redirect.

To summarize:

- festival.launch.co => events.launch.co/festival
- festival.launch.co/2013/ => Do Nothing for all files in this subdirectory

I've tried the following and this does not redirect anything:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^festival\.launch\.co$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2013
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://events.launch.co/festival/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've double-checked that mod_rewrite is enabled.

Currently, I'm redirecting everything:

```
Redirect 301 / http://events.launch.co/festival
```

Suggestions on how to do this properly?

Comment: Which URL isn't working for you? Do you have .htaccess inside `/2013/` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^festival\.launch\.co$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/2013/.*$
RewriteRule ^ http://events.launch.co/festival%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Just tried it and unfortunately it did not redirect anything. So frustrating! Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Nothing redirects when I used this. So, festival.launch.co, just stayed there. I put the original 301 redirect back as it's better for us to redirect everything than nothing. (This site is live).

Comment: Is mod_Rewrite enabled?

Comment: Yes, I've double-checked that.

Comment: I just opened `http://festival.launch.co` and it got redirected to `http://events.launch.co/festival`

Comment: Also can you post your complete & latest `.htaccess` in your question again? Do you have any other .htaccess anywhere like in 2013?

Comment: After your suggestion didn't work, I changed the .htaccess back to this: Redirect 301 / http://events.launch.co/festival. Which is why it's redirecting now.

Comment: The .htaccess I have now is: AddHandler php-stable .php
AddHandler php-script .html
Redirect 301 / http://events.launch.co/festival

Comment: Just looked 2013 and I don't see any other .htaccess files. Rather sure the only one I have is the one in the root directory. Thank you for all of the assistance by the way!

Comment: Ok made an edit, replace your 301 rule with this one. Also make sure to clear your browser cache since 301 is cached by browser.

Comment: Just noticed your comment above. Should I have the .htaccess in the 2013 folder as well?

Comment: No you don't need .htaccess in 2013? Just try latest code in root .htaccess

Comment: I just changed it to the above (go to festival.launch.co to see it). It's not redirecting anything unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm that's rght, it doesn't redirect. Can you comment `RewriteCond` and then let us retest.

Comment: Just did -- not redirecting.

Comment: Was I supposed to comment out both RewriteCond?

Comment: No only `RewriteCond %{REQUEUST_URI}`

Comment: This is hugely weird. Looks like mod_rewrite isn't even working. Can you add this rule just below `RewriteEngine On`: `RewriteRule ^foo$ / [L,R]`

Comment: Just added that, getting an internal error. I have to remove it, this is a live site.

Comment: Was it giving internal error for URLs other than `/foo` also?

Comment: Just an fyi -- I've put the Redirect 301 / http://events.launch.co/festival back in place for the time being. Let me know if you have any other thoughts, not sure what to do at this point. Thanks!

Comment: Ok in that case recheck if mod_rewrite is enabled & working. Create a php file with the code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and see what you get.

Comment: Hmm I checked that and its not giving any info on Apache `Loaded Modules`. When I do that on my end I get `mod_rewrite` in Apache `Loaded Modules`.

Comment: Check this post for verifying if mod_rewrite is enabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php

Comment: Made another edit. Try it out in .htaccess in a new temp folder under DOCUMENT_ROOT instead of main .htaccess

Comment: I've just tried to do the mod_write SO post and unfortunately I'm not technical enough to figure it out. I don't understand where to put the first answer. And nothing happens when I try the second answer: http://testing.launch.co/mod-test.php.

Comment: I've created testing.launch.co and tried the above updates. I changed 'festival' to 'testing' on line 3. Unfortunately it does not redirect anything: http://testing.launch.co. I also noticed that REQUEST was misspelled, was this intentional?

Comment: So sorry, misspelling was a typo, I have just fixed it. Can you try again?