# How to handle self generated URLs which doesn't exist in my server

Tags: .htaccess

Sorry if I didn't ask this question in the right way because I guess there may be duplicate questions on SO but I am new to this one so I don't really know the right words to search on.

I purposely generated some URLs which doesn't exists in my server. And its in two categories

1. mysite.com/blog/aRandomUrl
2. mysite.com/profile/aRandomUrl/aboutUser

Now those two URLs don't exist but I want to display a page for each URL.

I already handled the 404 error on my .htaccess file using this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pageNotFound.php
```

But I also want to read the URL in the browser if it looks like the first or second URL and display a page content else its displays the `pageNotFound.php`

Please how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to Rewrite URLs.

Its a bulky tutorial on its own but check out this article [URL Rewriting for Beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Also refer to this SO question [Mod_rewrite on WAMP 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152016/mod-rewrite-on-wamp-2-4)