# Codeigniter 2.1.4 installation in sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, subdirectory

I have successfully installed CI in the root directory many times, but now I have been forced to install CI in https://mydomain.com/mvc

There exists one controller "Login" with one action "index"

The .htaccess file looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /mvc  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://mydomain.com/mvc/';  
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

My routes look like:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "login";  
$route['login'] = "login/index";  
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

mod_rewrite is enabled
https://mydomain.com/mvc gives a 404
https://mydomain.com/mvc/login gives a 404
What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What´s your hosting? if is hostgator you need add your user.

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mvc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mvc/index.php/$1 [L]
```

if your hosting is hostgator you need add you name user, for example

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~<name_user>/%{HTTP_HOST} <or> <your folder>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~<name_user>/%{HTTP_HOST} <or> <your folder>/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The hosting company is softlayer.com

Comment: I did try this, same issue, a 404.

Comment: try checking if your mod_rewrite is active, you can read how to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php

Comment: Check your config.php?
$config['base_url'] = 'https://mydomain.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
Set you default base url for subdirectory

$config['base_url'] = "http://www.example.com/subdir/"

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. So you have just replace it

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

by

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This code run all sub directory. Hope this will help you!.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mvc/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I did  try this, same issue, a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I could fix it by updating `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file

try this.

### mvc/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

### mvc/application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://yourdomain.com/mvc/';
```

### /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    .... 

    <Directory /your/root/directory> # /var/www/html
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```