# url rewriting is not working (with Apache on Vagrant)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am trying to make a simple server for local PHP development with Vagrant on mac OS 10.9.4.

Vagrant is running inside the main "~/Sites" directory with "/var/www/html" on the guest pointing there. The Vagrantfile looks like this:

```rb
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/html"
```

On Apache, "000-default.conf" contains the default stuff, plus:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`mod_rewrite` was activated with `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

The 'Sites' folder contains several websites based on Wordpress, Kirby, or Drupal. Each website's folder contains only the 'public' files and its own `.htaccess` (-> then to be uploaded to the 'public_html' directory of their own production servers).

Apache, Php and MySql are working well and the first page of each project is visible at localhost:8080/project, but **it's impossible to navigate through the pages because url rewriting is not working** (pages not found like there was no htaccess files).

What should I do to make the url rewriting work?

Comment: What does `/var/log/apache2/error.log` say on the Guest?

Comment: Have you tried to verify that mod_rewrite is really loaded? => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php

Comment: Did you restart apache after `sudo a2enmod rewrite`?

Comment: Not sharing the "not working" .htaccess files leaves to answer the question a guessing game, so I only leave a link: [RewriteBase](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)