# Broken links after moving wordpress site

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I moved my wordpress site from local host to a live server. The problem is that all links from my nav won't work as the home button.
live site url: http://iulian.cablevision.ro
broken link example: http://iulian.cablevision.ro/about/

this is the error that i get:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.2.27 (CentOS) Server at iulian.cablevision.ro Port 80
```

I tried to use the a comand in SQL on my database to update urls:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'localhost/wordpres/', 'www.iulian.cablevision.ro/');
```

And I also tried to use the Velvet Blues pluginbut that didn't work as well... Is the another way to manipulate the database so my links will work properly?
I folowed the tutorial from http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/ but seams to not work for me... Wher is my mistake?

Comment: have you updated the `siteurl` and `homeurl` in the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the solution. It was the .htacces file the problem... The first mistake I did was that when I was uploading the .htacces file to the server it uploaded as simpe .txt file and the conversion to htacces file type didn't turn. So what I did:

- crated a simple text document with no name and uploaded to server
- after i uploaded the file i changed the name into .htacces so then the file conersion kicked in.

After that my links worked flawless. 
Thanks for the suport you guys gave me btw.

Answer (score 2):

first go to files and rename the htaccess file and then check your live site .it will help you surely.and if you have any issue regarding please descibe in detail

Answer (score 1):

For fixing all links after database migration, I use [this tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). After downloading, rename folder for example searchandreplace, add this folder to the root of WP site, access it www.yoursite.com/searchandreplace, and then enter the old site name and in replace input write your new one, but be sure that they both use same convention wording, if you write old site name www.oldsite.com, then new one should be www.newsite.com too, not http://* or something else added. Hope this helps if the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Your old server is not only in the `WP_POSTS` table, but also in other tables. See here how to move your wordpress site:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

> ```
> Download your existing site files.
> Export your database - go in to mySQL and export the database.
> Move the backed up files and database into a new folder - somewhere safe - this is your site backup.
> Log in to the site you want to move and go to Settings > General, then change the URLs. (ie from http://example.com/ to http://example.net ) - save the settings and expect to see a 404 page.
> Download your site files again.
> Export the database again.
> Edit wp-config.php with the new server's mySQL database name, user and password.
> Upload the files.
> Import the database on the new server.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a .htaccess if you are using permalink other than default structure  [copy from here](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess#Basic_WP)

Now that you have .htaccess try this

- Re save permalinks
- Check that your server has mod_rewrite enabled

Comment: I added a .htacces file now. And I changed the permisions to 744 but I can't edit it in wordpress permalinks option because it seams to not be writeble...

Comment: I checked if mod_rerite is enebled with a script from this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php and it seems is enabled

Comment: No don't edit any permalink just go to `admin panel->settings->permalinks` and click on `save changes` just to resave it.