# How to remove .html from url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove .html from url. For this i am trying following. But not sure what is wrong, not working in my case.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*).html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/demo/blog/test.html%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule .* %1.html [L]
```

I want to remove `.html` from this URL `http://localhost/demo/blog/test.html`.
So if someone enter this URL, `.html` should be removed from URL by htaccess
`http://localhost/demo/blog/test/`.

And need to add this rules only for blog directory.

I hope someone help me.

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled on your localhost?

Comment: Not sure. How to check?

Comment: Your example URL includes `/demo/blog/` but your code is expecting `/html/` - is this the actual code you are using?

Comment: @Hardik check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on

    # to make `/path/index.html` to /path/
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.html [NC]
    RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.html [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Comment: this is working only when i enter url without .html.

Answer (score 1):

First copy paste this code into your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Then change the web addresses on your navigation bar/link like this ↓
From `<a href="about.html">` to `<a href="about">`

It should work, also try not to put capital letters on your file names; It is not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

That should do it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Edit 1**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

**Edit 3**

As suggested in the comments, make sure that `mod_rewrite` is `enabled`. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php) link to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already tried this as well. Not working. :(

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled just checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules in `/demo/blog/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/blog/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)\.html?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```