# my codeigniter is not working on centos (internal server error 500)

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, centos, lamp

I'm kinda stuck right now. I just got a clean centos server with LAMP.

mysql is working AND httpd is working, but my codeigniter project is not.

I'm getting `500 Internal Server Error` so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my `.htaccess` file but I can't figure out what.

Normally I'm just using the following  (and that always does the trick)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

However this time it doesn't:

- my `mod_rewrite` is enabled
- just a simple php page with a echo is working so php running fine
- my mysql is up and running

Its just as soon as I put my codeigniter project on the server nothing happens

My access log says:

> [24/Sep/2014:10:01:50 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"

my error log doesnt say anything

I know there are alot of simular topics but so far i havent found the solution for my problem normally the answer is in the `.htaccess` file and its exactly like I have it

so Im totally lost atm and some help is appreciated.

**okay i fixed it turned out that my problem was NOT in the routing but that the correct DB drivers where not installed. and because the database library was already loaded in codeigniter just displayed blank pages with the 500 error**

[How do I configure php to enable pdo and include mysqli on CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747136/how-do-i-configure-php-to-enable-pdo-and-include-mysqli-on-centos)

**this was my exact problem and the answer was just install the drivers and its working now. :)**

Comment: Have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377876/codeigniter-500-internal-server-error?rq=1?

Answer (score 0):

did you already check the folder permission of the codeigniter folder?

if not then just use

```
chmod -R 777 codeigniter_folder
```

Comment: yes also the permissions are fine. already checked those. so still nothing happening

Comment: try to use my .htaccess file 
http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=TFGCCaGp

without ifModule tag

Comment: oke thanks looks like the .htaccess is working (suppose it worked all along) because i uploaded a clean new version of codeigniter and now i get the same issue WHEN i add the database module... so i need to look into another direction... i can connect to the database with no problems and everything is up and running but codeigniter doesnt tell me whats wrong with it, its just blank pages