# "This page isn’t working xxxxx.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I have an eCommerce project hosted with c panel but i cant seem to edit the controller the php files. When i do my web page doesn't load. Its not a ht access issue because my ht access file lacks permissions.
I used the codeigniter framework to build

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file say what the actual issue is? We cannot _guess_ that...

Comment: Can you show your controller folder screenshot here? As well as your base_url set in your config file. And htaccess file code.

Comment: `but i cant seem to edit the controller the php file` file permissions?

Comment: check you error logs.... 500 is usually a coding error sometimes it can be permissions if the file is not readable by the current user, such as for C-Panel you uploaded to the server as root but the C-Panel user is not root.

Comment: Please Mention Details of what exactly is your issue What e-commerce application are you using(if open source). What have you tried to fix this issue?  there are already many QAs Sufficient enough to troubleshoot your issues if you have gone through all of them lets know more details Consider visiting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377876/codeigniter-500-internal-server-error Check if you can fix, Controllers should start with a capital case in filename and class name. For more help Post your server error log and .httaccess here if you stllhave issues

Comment: I am using Active supershop here https://activeitzone.com/active_supershop

Answer (score 0):

Login to the server with root user and Check the logs at /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log , if its a permissions issue then to fix the permissions , google the cpanel permissions auto fix and you will get a script that has to be run in order to fix the permissions.